# What is the best way to show "Average" and "Max" of data usage per network in a chart?

Tags: charts, data-analysis

Actually, my initial thought was to give a toggle to choose between the two options (Average and Max). But then this will also be generated as a PDF report apart from the UI. Currently there's no option to configure the reports except for scheduling.

I'm thinking if this can be combined, but concerned about the number of data. Because, each of these networks will have two types of representation (avg and max). There will be at least 6 networks.

Or is it better to show it as two separate charts? Has anyone done anything similar to this?

Here's attached the mock.[image: The chart in the mock shows only Average values.]

The chart in the mock shows only Average values. Looking for suggestions. TIA.

Comment: so that x-axis is positive both up and down from 0? why not use two x-axis?

Comment: Your users need to compare the number of various networks, or they analyze each one separately? If you already have a mock with the toggle buttons for avg/max, show us please.

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach: User is more interested in seeing the max value of each network. So, yes the user would compare the max value between various networks.

No I don't have a mock for the toggle option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't mix average and maximum information, even in the screen.

You said you don't have a mockup of the toggle buttons for avg and max lines on the graph, but I believe that you have something like the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnVgdc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

My suggestion is to have 2 different graphs for max and avg information, because I believe that there is no need to the user to compare max and avg information, as they are different values. So, I suggest you to have something like the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzGWHA.png)</sup>

And you'll show only one line for each network, average OR maximum value.

Also, if it could be exported in PDF format, I agree with @SlavkoEror's answer that you should show 2 separate side-by-side charts on the PDF version, and using this way you keep PDF and web formats more similar, showing only one information type (max or avg).

You could have as well the two graphs side by side or stacked on the screen (which I believe is the best option, but it depends on the space you have on the page), showing the average in one and the maximum value on the other. So, you keep the PDF and web version exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, @DineiA.Rockenbach. I actually meant the latter option - segmented control option (toggle for max or avg). Yeah, I like your suggestions about handling it for web and PDF version. This makes more sense. Thank you so much for the sketch and coming forward to offer assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

I like your initial toggle idea. Can you set it up in a way that it shows as an Average vs. Max toggle for on screen display, and exports as 2 separate side-by-side charts on a PDF? That way you've maximized readability for each display method.

Comment: If users need to compare average and max, then you'll have to show both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This type of graph shows min, max, and average values together, in a visually simple way that doesn't require separate lines and labels for each type of value. (Min is zero, I assume in your case.)

[image: Sample Min-Max-Avg Chart]

I don't know the name of this type of graph, but Google seems to think it's a "min-max-average" graph.

Comment: I thinks it's a "box plot graph"

Comment: Thanks, Dinei. I'm no statistician, but it looks like box plots can show more points, the quartiles. We might call this a simplified box plot.

Comment: I am not a statistician either, so wondering how this can replace the line chart which provides the trend in data usage over a "time-series".

Comment: Yes, I see now that a box plot won't solve your original problem, which is that at each time point you have six data points (12 if you're showing both max and avg). Showing 12 box-plot elements at each point is going to be as problematic as 12 lines. Have you considered simply displaying the data as a table?